# What do you need to understand in order to be able to craft complex political intrigues with ease?

Tags: creative-writing, plot

What do you need to understand in order to be able to craft complex political intrigues with ease? I feel there are some missing pieces that prevent me from being productive in this area. I can't think of a good political intrigue that will make my story a lot more interesting and with full of unexpected turns.

Comment: It's going to depend a lot on place and time. The elements in the Imperial Chinese court or medieval Europe are very different to those in Trump's America when the focus is on appealing to (or deceiving) the masses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Many moving parts:

I won't say it's simple, because by definition intrigue is complex and deceptive. But to make political intrigue work, you need to have more moving parts (or perceived moving parts) than people can readily track.

- **WORLDBUILDING:**

The more complicated your story, the more competing interests there will be. If you have two political parties, six faiths, twelve ethnic groups, five social classes, and nine different foreign countries all clamoring for their voice to be heard, you'll have all the makings for intrigue that you need. Imagine the interest of each side, and especially imagine the potentially paradoxical things they might do for those goals.

- **CHARACTER DEVEOLOPMENT:**

But keeping track of all that requires a sophisticated political operative to manage those interests and somehow make 51% of them fall on your favor at any given time. So the manipulative power players must be significant characters to give political intrigue life. These fall into the incompetent but well-intentioned, the evil and uncaring out for their own gain, and the competent but flawed ideologs who believe in something (good and evil) and who have either lost their moral compass or are struggling not to lose their values.

- **PLOT DEVELOPMENT:**

But both competence and sophistication don't need to be real. You need to give your reader the impression of their cleverness (via attributed success or testimonials about their competence) and of the unseen actions controlling events (implied but often too hard to actually follow).

A good way to limit this access to make apparent complexity is to have point-of-view characters displaced by a degree from the power players. They don't see the actual activities of these titans directly, but instead see only the effects (good and bad). So a "good" power player is seen secretly ordering a rival's death, and the evil power player is seen advocating for a popular but cruel or selfish goal. The audience frequently wants to see political operatives as vicious and underhanded - even the ones working for the good guys.

If you can get the point-of view characters to go back and forth between power players and follow them, get betrayed by them, support their rivals, get disillusioned, and come back to follow the first operative with eyes wide open, you'll have the twists and turns you need.

Comment: This doesn't detract for the rest of the post, but I have doubts about that 51%. Gerrymandering, multi-tiered voting and political inequality means that there are situations where you need to represent much less of the genuine political interest to be in power. (And much more to change it.) And that's just considering a democracy.

Comment: @towr I didn't necessarily mean votes, but 51% of the available power. Sometimes this IS votes, but not always.

Comment: I think perhaps instead of "viscous" in the last sentence of the 2nd to last paragraph, you meant "vicious."

Answer (score 2):

First, you have the wrong goal wanting to write intrigue "with ease." Like any craft, someone who is good at it makes it look easy, but it's often very hard.

Second, most of these surprise twists and turns are written backwards. So X wants to replace Y in a surprise move by having all the votes, and by having Z be the one who calls for the vote, and by A and B happening to be away when the vote is called, and whatever other huge list of "coincidences" or hard-to-achieve things have to happen all at once. You're the writer. You start with that list. Then you go back through the book putting them in motion.

Do you do so transparently, having X show us (in narration or by telling another character or whatever) what will call both A and B away at the crucial moment? Or do you just show X having connections into A's and B's houses/families/courts so that it will be believable when the "big reveal" tells us that X's daughter did something specific that caused A and B to have to go deal with it and not be at the big vote? That's your choice, to reveal the intrigue bit by bit, so this is a book **about** intrigue, or to have a Big Twist that all works together at the end, so it's a book that **uses** intrigue to get its plot done. (The latter is a little easier because you don't have to sew up every loose end and rebut every possible "but surely B would just" in the reader's mind.)

You will probably need separate documents where you keep track of who is secretly bribing who, which secrets are known to which characters, which lies have been told and so on. It will doubtless be quite difficult. But that's ok: it's part of the work.